# SceneKit Crash when move finger change scncamrea's position quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, uiscrollview, scenekit

iPhoen8 Plus,iOS 11(15A372), Xcode9(9A235)

I load a scn file to show the 3D object.This is my code.This modelView will
as subView on a UIView, the UIView is the subView on UIScrollView.When I touch and move my finger, scnview's object will do some rotation. If I move quickly, it crashed.

```
// ModelView.m : SCNView
+ (instancetype)modelWithxxx {
    ModelView *model = [[ModelView alloc] initWithFrame:MODELVIEWRECT];
    model.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"xxx.scn"];
    return model;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.allowsCameraControl = YES;
        self.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]

It looks like ScnView's bug, I don't know what happen, I just load the .scn file and use cameracontrol.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be a SNCView bug. It happens to me as well, only in iOS 11. Did you fill a bug report?

Comment: @JoseJavierGrossoGardón Not yep. I trying do find out the steps to reproduce. In new project, I new a scrollview, and add a scnview as scrollview's subview.I move finger  quickly. The scnview didn't crash. Do you know this bug how to  reproduce?

My scrollview has many subviews, are you ?